# What does '&&' operator indicate with { this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { foo:this.foo})

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have react class that is rendered using react router. I understand that React.cloneElement is used to pass elements from parent to child. But why/what does the '&&' operator do with this kind of statement :

```
class Users extends React.Component {
    getInitialState() {
      return {
          page:0
        }
     },      
    foo(){
        this.setState({'page':1})
     }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Users</h2>
            { this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    foo:this.foo})
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

I would like to understand why are we using '&&' operator here.

Answer (score 65):

It's **Short circuit evaluation**

```
(if this part is true) && (this part will execute)
```

And it shorthand of:

```
if(condition){
   (this part will execute)
}
```

Comment: Looks like it saves having to do :null for ternaries

Comment: Is this only a react thing?

Answer (score 17):

The && is the exact same operator as you would find in any javascript expression, such as...

```
if( condition1 && condition2) {

}
```

It is a feature of javascript that an expression of the form...

```
(condition1 && condition2)
```

will evaluate to condition2, if condition1 is true, or null if condition1 is false.  It is effectively shorthand for...

```
if(condition1) {
    condition2;
}
```

We use this shorthand by placing a React element as condition 2, getting...

```
(condition1 && <ReactElement />)
```

which is effectively...

```
if(condition1) {
    <ReactElement />
}
```

Comment: So `condition2` is not really a condition as it depends only on `condition1` ?

Answer (score 9):

When && and || are used in this way, they are nicknamed "short circuit operators". In this usage, it can be thought of as a quickie "if (something is true)". So, if this.props.children is not null, it will call React.cloneElement. If it is null, it will not call React.cloneElement.

Here is a link on the official React documentation, with further reading: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical-ampamp-operator

Answer (score 3):

In simple words the purpose of that `&&` is:

> Do not attempt to clone and render children when there are no
>   children.

So if you use `Users` like this:

```
<Users>
   <Child1 />
   <Child2 />
</Users>
```

then both `Child1` and `Child2` will get rendered with additional props `foo`.

But if the parent is used in this way `<Users/>` or `<Users></Users>`, there are no child components to render. So we are performing a check before we invoke `React.cloneElement`.

**`&&` is equivalent to boolean `AND`:** `1 AND A === A` => `1 && A = A`

**`||` is equivalent to boolean `OR`:** `1 OR A = 1` => `1 || A = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You could drop that first clause and just use `React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {foo:this.foo})`, but it's included in your example to account for cases where there are no child components to be rendered.