# What is the logic behind the "&&" operator here?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I know that when we use the "&&", the logic is like this:{ boolean && action } -> if the boolean is *true* then return the "action". In my code it happens like this: if the `src` property exists, then return the `<Avatar />`. My question is: why is it like this? src doesn't have any true or false value. Why it happens like this ?

```js
function Sidebar({src}) {
    return (
        <div>
            {src && <Avatar src={src} />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does '&&' operator indicate with { this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { foo:this.foo})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682064/what-does-operator-indicate-with-this-props-children-react-cloneelemen)

Comment: If your question is, `Although "src" isn't a boolean value, why is the "&&" operator working?` The answer is: it doesn't look for a boolean value, it checks whether the value is truthy or falsy. All [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values are considered to be boolean false. and the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) of them are boolean true.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about this truthy or falsy concept. Now everything is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> src doesn't have any true or false value

It has a value (even if that value is `undefined` or `null`) that is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) even if that value isn't a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

src can have undefined or null value. So to avoid this.

First we are checking if `src` contains valid data which is neither `undefined` nor `null` And if that condition is true then we are passing that source to `Avatar` as `props`.

Comment: (Or `false` etc; I'd use "falsey" here since it's not doing an explicit type check.)

Comment: Agree. @DaveNewton

Answer (score 0):

Just operator of javascript `&&` operator will return last one if others in ahead different `flase` (each others != flase)

```js
//just operator of javascript // && operator will return last one if //others in ahead different flase (mean others != flase)

let object = {a:1};

console.log(object && 1);
console.log(object && 1 && object);
console.log(null && object);
```