# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

So I'm creating a e-commerce store for a sideproject, but I'm stuck on a problem.
On the main page I have all the products, and I've created a route for the product details. When I click on one of them, it gets the id, and should output all the product details. I have the details about products in a JSON array "data.js".

When I click on a product in the main page, it displays the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined` - in the `return` part, where I put `{product.image}` in.

However, when I uncomment the part where it checks whether product exists or not (ProductPage.js), it still outputs `"Item does not exist!"`, as if there weren't any data about the product in "data.js" file.

App.js

```
<Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductPage}></Route>
```

ProductPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data';

export default function ProductPage(props) {
const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === props.match.params.id);
// if (!product) {
//     return <div>Item does not exist!</div>
// }
return (
    <div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
                <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Data.js

```
const data = {
products:[
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'iPhone 11 Pro',
    category: 'Smartphones',
    image: '/images/2.jpg',
    price: 949,
    rating: 4.8,
    numReviews: 15,
    description: 'testtesttesttesttesttesttesttest',
},
],
};
export default data;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your ProductPage component with **withRouter** to access **props.match.params.id**.

**Edit**: if you are going to use **props.match.params.id** for comparison, keep in mind that it is a string

Change your ProductPage component to:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

function ProductPage(props) {
const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === props.match.params.id);
return (
    <div>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
                <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default withRouter(ProductPage);
```

Comment: Still does not work - although it does access the props.match.params.id (tried with console.log), shows the same error.

Comment: The problem may be due to the comparison of string with a number. props.match.params.id is a string where as your _id in data is a number.
Try x._id.toString() === props.match.params.id  or x._id === parseInt(props.match.params.id)

Answer (score 0):

import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

this method doesn't work I have tried it.

**Solution that worked for me:**

instead of just using product.image use product && product.image.

<img src={product && product.image} alt={product.name}>

For more on Conditional rendering (&&) please check the link below:

[What does '&&' operator indicate with { this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { foo:this.foo})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682064/what-does-operator-indicate-with-this-props-children-react-cloneelemen)

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting an answer/question, please look into how to format your answer to make it easier to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Thanks for posting answers on SO!