# How to pass params into link using React router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my main section class where all routes to the links is kept

```
export default class Section extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{backgroundColor:"white"}}>
                   <Routes>
                   <Route path="/"  element={<Home/>} />
                    <Route path="/discover" element={<Discover/>}   />
                    <Route path="/shop/makeup" element={<Makeup/>}  />
                    <Route path="/home/:id" element={<DetailsPage/>}  />
                    </Routes>
            </div>
        )}}
```

This is my card page which is getting data from the context.

```
import React from 'react';
import {DataContext} from './CardData.js';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../App.css';
export default class HomeCard extends React.Component {
    static contextType = DataContext;
    render(){
        const {products} = this.context;
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card">
                { products.map((val,index)=>{
                   return(
                    <div className="card" key={val.id}>
                    <Card style={{ width: '14rem' }}  className="cardhead">
  <Card.Img variant="top" src={val.imgsrc} className="cardimg"/>
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Text>{val.mname}
    </Card.Text>
    <Card
```

From here i had passed the val.id to the url of the page using LINK

```
    <Link to={`/home/${val.id}`}>
    <Button className="overlay" variant="primary">
      {/* <a  style={{color:"white"}} href={props.link} className="card-link">View</a> */}
      View</Button> </Link>
    <Card.Text><strong>{val.price}</strong>
    </Card.Text>
    <Card.Text><strong>{val.id}</strong>
    </Card.Text>
    </Card.Footer>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
</div>);                
    </div>
  )}}
```

I want to access the the link url into the details page of my product which is as follows :

```
export default class DetailsPage extends React.Component {
    static contextType = DataContext;
    state = {
        product: []
    }
    getProduct = () =>{
        if(this.props.match.params.id){
            const res = this.context.products;
            const data = res.filter(item =>{
                return item.id === this.props.match.params.id
            })
            this.setState({product: data})
        }};
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getProduct();
    }
    render() {
        const {product} = this.state;
        const {addCart} = this.context;
        return (
            <>
                {product.map(item =>(
                        <div className="details" key={item.id}>
                            <img src={item.imgsrc} alt=""/>
                            <div className="box">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <h2>{item.mname}</h2>
                                    <span>${item.price}</span>
                                </div>
                                <Link to="/cart" className="cart" onClick={() => addCart(item.id)}>
                                    Add to cart
                                </Link>
                            </div>   </div>  ))} </> )  }}
```

Unfortunately it is giving an error saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: Is the `<Link to={`/home/${val.id}`}>` path correct? What is rendering, and where, the `HomeCard` component? I know react-router-dom-v6 uses relative paths so perhaps I just have my bearings in your snippets.

Comment: yes this path is correct  it is rendering a product with id passed in the url Link {val.id}. It is rendering in the detailsPage component

Comment: @Beren  Hope this may help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727803/react-typeerror-cannot-read-property-image-of-undefined/64727955#64727955)

Comment: Dark shadow no it doesn't worked .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Navigate programmatically

#### Send parameters to `useNavigate`

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

```
 function _navigateToPage (pageNumber) {
    const page = pageNumber
    const title = "Hello World";
    navigate("/fragment", {
      state:{
          page,
          title
        },
    });

  }
```

### Retrieve parameters in other page with `useLocation`

```js
const params = useLocation();
console.log(params);
```

Comment: can you also include the "Route", how its should be defined? Also I thought state will be like key value ?  { state: { id: order.id } } . what is page and title above ?

Answer (score 62):

## Using react-router-dom v6

#### Parent component (App)

```js
<Route path="/something/:id" element={<Something />} />
```

#### Child component (Something)

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Something = (props) => {

    let { id } = useParams(); 

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`/something/${id}`);
    },[]);

    // .....

}
```

Comment: A quick and exact solution. Thanks for the details. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 44):

## Issue(s)

1. react-router-dom v6 `Route` components rendered via the `element` prop don't receive [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).
2. Route children components ***must*** use react hooks to access the route context, i.e. `useParams`, `useLocation`, `useNavigate`, etc... and therefore must be function components.
3. There no longer exists a `withRouter` Higher Order Component.

## Solution

`DetailsPage` is a class-based component so I see a couple options for getting access to the route's match params.

1. Convert `DetailsPage` to be a function component and use the `useParams` react hook.
2. Write your own `withRouter` HOC to access the route context and pass as props any of the react-hook accessible values.

I won't cover converting a class-based component to a function component, but can provide a simple HOC solution to pass to `DetailsPage` (*or any other class-based component*) the match params.

```
const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const params = useParams();
  // etc... other react-router-dom v6 hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      params={params}
      // etc...
    />
  );
};
```

You can now wrap & export your class-based components in the *very familiar* way they were from v4/v5.

Comment: Yeah it solved my issue. I just converted my class component into the functional one .Thanks for Helping Drew Reese

Comment: This should somehow be highlighted in the documentation.

Comment: @Tanckom Agreed. It took me way too long to figure out why v5 methods were not working and why I am forced to use functional components for some reason that is never motivated or even mentioned at all.

Comment: @BramVanroy From React's perspective they've made it pretty clear that function components are the future of React; they only still support class components for compatibility. Since the introduction of [hooks in 16.8.0](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html) my team hasn't written a single class component. That's in almost 3 years. I can understand why libraries such as `react-router-dom` release a major update with effectively a full rewrite. IIRC there's a RRD blog out there somewhere that explains the impetus for the v6 changes, but the official docs also help explain why.

Answer (score 30):

Pass props via Link component in React Router v6 by a separate prop called `state` like `<Link to="/" state={{ foo: bar }}>`.

Example:

```
   <Link
      to={`/login`}
      state={{ from: "the-page-id" }}
   >
      Login to see this page
   </Link>
```

And retrieve it using `useLocation()` hook:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
...
  const location = useLocation();
  const { from } = location.state;
  console.log(from); // output: "the-page-id"
```

This should be used with function components only not class components.

Comment: And How in Class Coponents

Comment: @Anmol `npm i react-router-dom@5` then `<Link to={{ pathname: "/login, state: { from: "the-page-id" } }} >`

Comment: useLocation is exactly what I needed, thanks for this comment

Answer (score 21):

I had this same problem and scoured the internet for an easy solution. I didn't want to rewrite all my class components as functional components but I thought I might have to. However, I used a withRouter function with useParams() and it works really well and is easy to follow.

To solve your problem so you don't have to rewrite your DetailsPage class as a function, follow these steps:

1. Add the following line of code at the beginning of your class:

   ```
    import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
   ```
2. Then add this function above your class (copy it exactly):

   ```
    export function withRouter(Children){
        return(props)=>{

           const match  = {params: useParams()};
           return <Children {...props}  match = {match}/>
       }
     }
   ```
3. Next, change your class definition to this:

   ```
    class DetailsPage extends React.Component {
   ```
4. Add the following line of code at the end of your class:

   ```
    export default withRouter(DetailsPage);
   ```

Comment: This worked perfectly for Class Component. Thanks, you saved a lot of time

Comment: This is the only "clear" instructions that I have found for a quick work around for class based components. This answer is simple, easy to follow and the code works!

Comment: This explanation is excellent for a beginner