# How do I pass props to a component passed as an element prop to a Route in React-Router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Just as the title says, I want to know how to pass props to a React component that is passed to a Route as its `element` prop.

So, for this code

```
<Route path="/" element={<App />} >
    <Route path="table" element={<Table />} />
</Route>
```

How do I pass props to `Table`?

Comment: You mean like `<Table {...props}>`?

Comment: No. I'm referring to: ```<Table someProp={aValue} />```

Comment: Uhh, just like you've done, `<Table someProp={aValue} />`. Are you having an issue with passing props this way?

Comment: If the props are coming from the ```<App />``` component, then yes. Since I cannot access variables and functions that are inside ```<App />```. In any case, I managed to pass props by creating a ```<Routes />``` component inside ```<App />```.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is specifically that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Hey maybe this will be useful to you:

[How to pass params into link using React router v6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782949/how-to-pass-params-into-link-using-react-router-v6)