# Axios can't get the obejct Id react

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, mern

I have a component DetailPage.js, that lists items thought axios get, that I wish returns that specific object user clicks on in order to get more details. But it returns an empty object. ID is undefined. console
How link id of object to specific url?

Here is my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import CreateUser from "./components/CreateUser";
import DetailPage from "./components/DetailPage";
import EditUser from "./components/EditUser";
import LandingPage from "./components/LandingPage";
import Header from "./components/Header";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className='container'>
        <Header />
            <Routes>
            <Route path="/add" element={<CreateUser/>}/>
            <Route path="/user/:id" element={<DetailPage/>}/>
            <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

this is DetailPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

export default class DetailPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        users: [],
    };
}


  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/detail/${id}`)
         .then(res => {
             this.setState({ users: res.data.users });
         })
         .catch(error => {
             console.log(error)
         });
   
   }



  render() {
    const { name, email, phone, loc, date } = this.state.users;
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{name}</h4>
        <hr />
        <dl className="row">
          <dt className="col-sm-2">Email</dt>
          <dd className="col-sm-10">{email}</dd>
          <dt className="col-sm-2">Phone</dt>
          <dd className="col-sm-10">{phone}</dd>
          <dt className="col-sm-2">Location</dt>
          <dd className="col-sm-10">{loc}</dd>
          <dt className="col-sm-2">Date</dt>
          <dd className="col-sm-10">{date}</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router Pass Param to Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898789/react-router-pass-param-to-component)

Comment: See also [How to pass params into link using React router v6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64782949/283366)

Comment: Hi @Phil, I think I got the error because most of my codes are running on the V5, and some are running on the v6, I need to rewrite some of my codes.