# React JS : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: reactjs

after i finished a cours about react i tried to create a git engine app using git api and i got this problem when i tried to catch the url param using "this.props.match.params.login"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxPIH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD3n2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfu0u.png)

any help please !! thanks in advance

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782949/how-to-pass-params-into-link-using-react-router-v6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a functional component to get the params of a route path:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const { yourParam } = useParams();
  console.log(yourParam);
  // the rest of your logic
}
```

**Edit:**

According to [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq), v6 fully embraced hooks and use them to share all the router's internal state.
However, in class-based components you can use a wrapper to get the params of a route path.

In your **App.js**, add the following snippet:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

const InfoRoute = withRouter(Info);
```

Then, in your Routes (still in App.js) use the new component:

```
<Route path='/allUsers/:login' element={<InfoRoute />} />
```

Finally, in your **info.js**, you can get the ***login*** param from the path url as follows:

```
this.props.router.params.login
```

Comment: yo sir, yes it works but i cant use it with stats i want to recover the link param in class component to be able to use states and fetch the data from api

Comment: I don't think they will be able to use the useParams hook, as their `Info` component is a class component, which cannot use hooks.