# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'Partial<Path>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to open new tab when click the component in react `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"` follow this [docs](https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-router-passing-data-states-through-links/), this is the code I am using right now:

```
<Link
      to="/app/cruise/article/detail"
      target="_blank"
      state={record}
    >Detail</Link>
```

but when I recieve the value like this in the distination page:

```
const stateData: any = location.state;
```

the result is undefined. what should I do to recieve the passed value? I have already tried this way:

```
<Link
      to={{
      pathname: `/app/cruise/article/detail`,
      state: { 
        record: record 
      },
      }}/>
```

show error like this:

```
(property) record: API.InterviewListItem
Type '{ pathname: string; state: { record: API.InterviewListItem; }; }' is not assignable to type 'To'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'Partial<Path>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(53, 5): The expected type comes from property 'to' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'
```

this is my detail page to receive the state value:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import { connect, Dispatch, IArticleState, Loading } from 'umi';

interface ArticleDetailProps {
  articles: IArticleState
  dispatch: Dispatch
  channelListLoading: boolean
}

const ArticleDetail: React.FC<ArticleDetailProps> = ({articles, dispatch, channelListLoading}) => {

  const location = useLocation();
  const stateData: any = location.state;
  debugger

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    //alert(location);
    debugger
    if(stateData){
      dispatch({
        type: 'articles/getArticleDetail',
        payload: stateData.record.id
      });
    }
  },[]);

  let articleData = articles.data;
  
  return (
   <div>
      <h2>{articleData.title}</h2>
     <div style={{fontSize:'15px'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: articleData.content}} />
   </div>
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = ({articles, loading}: {articles: IArticleState, loading: Loading}) => {
   return {
      articles,
      userListLoading: loading.models.articles
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
      dispatch
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticleDetail);
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass `state` data to a new tab.. you have to use query string..

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the react router docs page you should pass the state as a property of the object **to** like this:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/app/cruise/article/detail",
    state: record
  }}
  target="_blank"
>Detail</Link>
```

Docs: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

Comment: I have tried this way, did not work. @poal98 The new version did not work like this.

Comment: You are right. It looks like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782949/how-to-pass-params-into-link-using-react-router-v6 they talk about the same thing and you are following the correct way. Maybe then the problem is related to something else (it could also be the record object)

Answer (score 1):

For me on the `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"` is working in this way:

I can send the state using:

```
<Link to={`/url/${genre.id}`}  state={{ key: "value" }} className="list-group-item">
```

And get using the `useLocation()` method

```
const location = useLocation();
console.log(location.state.key)
```