# How to get id from url (react-router-dom v 6) for class component ReactJS (v 18)

Tags: reactjs

My router looks like this::

```
    <Routes>
              <Route path="/:userId" render={(props) => <Home {...props}/>}  element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
```

Here is my component::

```
    import { Component } from 'react'
    export default class Home extends Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }
    
      render() {
        console.log(this.match)
        return(
            <div>
              <h2>111</h2>
            </div>
          )
    }
    }
```

As a result, in the console I get:

```
    undefined
```

Question: what am I doing wrong? Why can't I get an id?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782949/how-to-pass-params-into-link-using-react-router-v6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass params into link using React router v6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782949/how-to-pass-params-into-link-using-react-router-v6)

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
console.log(this.props.match)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. The result is the same

Comment: Maybe this will solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/70733535/19087521

Comment: #pinchers, Yes, that's exactly how I solved this problem yesterday. Found the same solution here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8146#issuecomment-947860640