# How to check if user is logged by localStorage and Redirect according to it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-router-dom

I am new to localStorage and React Router, and my goal is:
Redirect user to the "/dashboard" when he is logged in, and Redirect back to '/home' when he is logged out. Also, of course, not allowing him to go to the 'dashboard' if he is not logged in. For some reason my code in App.js not working:

```
function App() {
  let userLogged;

  useEffect(() => {
    function checkUserData() {
      userLogged = localStorage.getItem("userLogged");
    }

    window.addEventListener("storage", checkUserData);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", checkUserData);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            {userLogged ? (
              <Route path={"/dashboard"} element={<Dashboard />} />
            ) : (
              <Route path={"/home"} element={<Home />} />
            )}
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I set it in the home and dashboard pages by `localStorage.setItem('userLogged', false)` and `localStorage.setItem('userLogged', true)`

Comment: How is your code not working? Is there any error. You need to tell how it's not working

Comment: @charchit it doesn't redirect to the pages (home, dashboard) when it has to. when i log out, it does not go to home, and when i am at home still not logged in, i can go to /dashboard easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only listen to changes in localStorage from other window/browser contexts, not from within the same browser/window context. Here it's expected the window knows its own state. In this case, you ***actually*** need some React state.

Convert the `userLogged` to a React state variable and use a `useEffect` hook to initialize and persist the `userLogged` state to/from localStorage. Instead of conditionally rendering `Route` components, create a wrapper component to read the `userLogged` value from localStorage and conditionally render an `Outlet` for nested/wrapped routes ***or*** a `Navigate` component to redirect to your auth route to login.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthWrapper = () => {
  const location = useLocation(); // current location

  const userLogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLogged"));

  return userLogged
    ? <Outlet />
    : (
      <Navigate
        to="/"
        replace
        state={{ from: location }} // <-- pass location in route state
      />
    );
};
```

...

```
function App() {
  const [userLogged, setUserLogged] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLogged"))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("userLogged", JSON.stringify(userLogged));
  }, [userLogged]);

  const logIn = () => setUserLogged(true);
  const logOut = () => setUserLogged(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home logIn={logIn} />} />
            <Route path={"/home"} element={<Home logIn={logIn} />} />
            <Route element={<AuthWrapper />}>
              <Route path={"/dashboard"} element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = ({ logIn }) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const loginHandler = () => {
    // authentication logic

    if (/* success */) {
      const { from } = state || {};

      // callback to update state
      logIn();
      // redirect back to protected route being accessed
      navigate(from.pathname, { replace: true });
    }
  };

  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems working when I check it with console! The only problem is that it doesn't actually navigate it to the dashboard when i log in. When I press button onClick on login page i trigger this: localStorage.setItem('userLogged', true), but it doesnt happen to go to dashboard page. same with logout. Do you know why does it happen?

Comment: @user18150656 It's because `localStorage.setItem('userLogged', true)` isn't updating any React state and doesn't trigger a rerender. The button `onClick` should trigger a callback that updates the `userLogged` state (*e.g. the source of truth*) that the `useEffect` hook persists to localStorage. When the `userLogged` state updates, `App` is rerendered and the correct route will be matched/rendered. I'll update with a code example to redirect a user to the route they were originally trying to access.

Comment: thanks a lot for your helping over here. since I use class, I had to use it in such a way: `if (/* success */) { this.props.logIn() this.setState({ count: 1 }) }` and in render return method: `this.state.count === 1 ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />` and it works, I can log in, but when I refresh the page, it automatically goes back to default home. in the authWrapper userLogged value also becomes false. can I ask you for help please in this situation?

Comment: @user18150656 No worries. If necessary you can create a custom `withRouter` HOC to use the hooks and inject the `location` and `navigate` as props. If you've created an `AuthWrapper` wrapper component for the routes and initialized the `userLogged` state directly from localStorage then there shouldn't be an issue with page reloads as this is all synchronous code. It kind of sounds like your initial question here has been addressed, so if you like you can ask a new on-topic question with the new code. Feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to any new posts.

Comment: Thanks, I will try couple of more times, if I won't be able to do it, I'll update you tomorrow. checking your answer as the best solution. thanks again.

Comment: @user18150656 Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64816926/8690857) of mine that demos the `withRouter` HOC implementation for `react-router-dom@6` if it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can render both route and use `Navigate` component to redirect. Like this -

```
// [...]
<Route path={"/dashboard"} element={<Dashboard />} />
<Route path={"/home"} element={<Home />} />
{
userLogged ?
<Navigate to="/dashboard" /> :
<Navigate to="/home" />
}
// other routes
```

Whenever you logout, you need to manually redirect to the desired page using [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate) hook.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work since I can't use Navigate under <Routes>