# React-router with localStorage renews to default after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-router-dom

This is my previous question, where I solved one problem but now struggling with another: [How to check if user is logged by localStorage and Redirect according to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72466016/how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-by-localstorage-and-redirect-according-to-it#72466607)

I have home page, where user logges in, and dashboard page, when user logs out. Right now if I log into dashboard, after renewing the page, localStorage' 'userLogged' value goes to false again and redirects to /home (I consoled it out in App.js and AuthWrapper.js). What is my problem?

**App.js**

```
function App() {

  const [userLoggedState, setUserLogged] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLogged"))
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("userLogged", JSON.stringify(userLoggedState))
  }, [userLoggedState])

  const logIn = () => setUserLogged(true)
  const logOut = () => setUserLogged(false)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home logIn={logIn} />} />
            <Route element={<AuthWrapper />}>
              <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home logIn={logIn} />} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**AuthWrapper.js**

```
export const AuthWrapper = () => {
    const location = useLocation()

    const userLogged = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userLogged"))

    return userLogged
        ? <Outlet />
        : <Navigate
            to="/"
            replace
            state={{ from: location }}
        />
}
```

**Home.js**

```
    export default class Home extends Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                userLogged: false,
                count: 0
            }
        }
    
        componentDidMount() {
            const userLogged = localStorage.getItem('userLogged')
            this.setState({ userLogged })
        }
    
        listenToUserStatus = (value) => {
            this.setState({ userLogged: value })
            localStorage.setItem('userLogged', value)
            if (value) {
                this.props.logIn()
                this.setState({ count: 1 })
            }
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    {
                        this.state.count === 1 ? <Navigate to={"/dashboard"} replace /> :
                            <>
                                <Navbar className="navbar">
                                    <Container>
                                        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Website</Navbar.Brand>
                                    </Container>
                                </Navbar>
                                <HomeComponent
                                    listenToUserStatus={this.listenToUserStatus}
                                />
                                <Navbar className="navbar footer" fixed="bottom">
                                    <Container>
                                        <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-center">
                                            <Navbar.Text>
                                                Website {new Date().getFullYear()} © All Rights Reserved.
                                        </Navbar.Text>
                                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                                </Container>
                            </Navbar>
                        </>
                }
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `listenToUserStatus` in the `Home` component? What is `HomeComponent` doing with it? The `logIn` and `logOut` functions in `App` handle setting the localStorage so nothing else in the app should also be setting localStorage values for the `userLogged` state.

Comment: @DrewReese it's just another child component which sends 'true' if LogIn button has been pressed. After I removed all the setItem's from home and dashboard pages, worked like charm. Thanks Drew!