# How to use match.params.id in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
at matchPath (utils.ts:622:1)

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetching = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/notes/${match.params.id}`);

      setTitle(data.title);
      setContent(data.content);
      setCategory(data.category);
      setDate(data.updatedAt);
    };

    fetching();
  }, [match.params.id, date]);
```

Comment: will [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64782949/11737596) ?

Comment: If the error is something to do with reading a "path" in a `matchPath` utility, why are you asking about `match.params.id`? Can you edit the post to include the complete error message and the accompanying code stacktrace? A more complete [mcve] would also be helpful to see what is going on around this code and the code that is possibly generating the error. Also, careful using `date` as a dependency since you are updating that state in the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use useParams() from react-router-dom

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Component =()=>{
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetching = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/notes/${id}`);

      setTitle(data.title);
      setContent(data.content);
      setCategory(data.category);
      setDate(data.updatedAt);
    };

    fetching();
  }, [id, date]);
}
```

in your Route

```
<Route exact path="/user/:id" element={<Component />} />
```

Comment: hye bro you are great thanks alot bro keep growing 
Tarun Bisht