# React - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined" while styling with CSS

Tags: reactjs

I am new to web development and React, and I would kindly ask for some help related to my current project.

I am accessing data from a local file and trying to display them on click. It works fine if I don't touch anything related to styling, but every time I add some CSS my code breaks.

I guess ny question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727803/react-typeerror-cannot-read-property-image-of-undefined), but this solution doesn't work for me. I am not even able to add a div tag! Can anybody suggest what to do?
Thanks!

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "../womenInfo.css";

function WomanDetails({ routeProps, data }) {
 const foundCard = () => {
    return data.find((card) => card.id === +routeProps.match.params.id);
};
return (
    <div className="woman-page">
        <>
            <img className="info-img" src={foundCard().image} alt="" />
        </>
        <>
            <h3 className="women-title">{foundCard().title}</h3>
        </>
        <>
            <p className="women-years">{foundCard().years}</p>
        </>
        <>
            <p className="women-nationality">{foundCard().nationality}</p>
        </>
        <>
            <p className="women-contribution">{foundCard().contribution}</p>
        </>
    </div>
 );
}

export default withRouter(WomanDetails);
```

Comment: I think `foundCard()` method returns undefined that's why you are facing error.
what is meaning of plus sign here `+routeProps.match.params.id`

Comment: You need to use like `foundCard()[0].image` since `foundCard()` functions returns an array. Do the same for title, nationality etc.

Comment: @TechySharnav I think he is using find method so it will not return array.

Comment: @TechySharnav `Array,prototype.find` returns a matched element or undefined, not an array.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I mistook `find` for `filter`

Comment: @PriyankKachhela `+routeProps.match.params.id` attempts type coercion to `Number`.

Comment: OP, why not `const foundCard = data.find((card) => card.id === +routeProps.match.params.id);` and apply some conditional rendering if `foundCard` is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

[Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) can potentially return undefined if no element in the array matches.

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the
> provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no
> values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

If `foundCard()` returns undefined then `foundCard().image` will throw the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined”` error you are seeing.

## Solution

Simplify `foundCard` from function to an assignment expression. Check the `foundCard` value and if falsey (undefined, null, false) then return `null` early to indicate there is nothing to render.

The React `Fragment`s are also only necessary when returning more than a single node and you don't want to muddy up the DOM with `div` "containers". They don't need to surround each single element.

```
function WomanDetails({ routeProps, data }) {
  const foundCard = data.find((card) => card.id === +routeProps.match.params.id);

  if (!foundCard) return null;

  return (
    <div className="woman-page">
      <img className="info-img" src={foundCard.image} alt="" />
      <h3 className="women-title">{foundCard.title}</h3>
      <p className="women-years">{foundCard.years}</p>
      <p className="women-nationality">{foundCard.nationality}</p>
      <p className="women-contribution">{foundCard.contribution}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(WomanDetails);
```