# conditional variable === "something" &&

Tags: javascript, reactjs

why this coditional is not working:

```
   {
        selectedConfig === "house"      ||
        selectedConfig === "Zone"          ||
        selectedConfig === "Departament"  &&
        <div>
            <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2">
                <InputForn 
                    text="Nom"
                    name="nom"
                    inputType="text"
                    value=""
                />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2">
                <InputForn 
                    text="URL "
                    name="url"
                    inputType="text"
                    value=""
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

It's react js, I'm creating one conditional to show/hide some component, so currently It's showing when I select `Departament` but not work when conditional are `house or zone`

I think that operator `||` not work, why?? or what can I do to work it ???

Comment: so, it's showing exactly when it should, given the conditional you provided?

Comment: This was closed as dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682064/what-does-operator-indicate-with-this-props-children-react-cloneelemen), but that Q&A doesn't answer this question at all. Voted to reopen.

Comment: As pointed out, your missing some brackets to enforce precedence.  But another idea instead of all those OR, maybe create a constant `Set` and use `.has` to check,..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parens.

```js
(  selectedConfig === "house"
|| selectedConfig === "Zone"
|| selectedConfig === "Departament"
) && ...
```

---

The problem is that `&&` has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `||`.

This means that

```js
a || b || c && d
```

is equivalent to

```js
a || b || ( c && d )
```

But you want

```js
( a || b || c ) && d
```

---

As an aside, you say you want to check for `zone`, but you check for `Zone`. You are using inconsistent capitalization, and you misspelled "department". This is error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group conditions with parentheses :

```
(selectedConfig === "house" || selectedConfig === "Zone" || selectedConfig === "Departament")
```